# Android Listener interrupts Listener

Tags: android, listener, interrupt

I'm working on remote controling. There is a car, it has servo + esc, and they are connected to arduino, which is connected to wifi shield.
On other side I have android tablet, which sends data to arduino to control a car.
There is a source code for android app:

```
package rccardriver.app;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket=null;
    private SeekBar steeringControl = null;
    private SeekBar speedControl = null;
    private Button btn=null;
    DataOutputStream DOS = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);
        steeringControl =(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.steering_bar);
        speedControl =(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.speed_bar);
        steeringControl.setMax(75);
        speedControl.setMax(180);
        speedControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                try {
                    DOS.write(0x01);
                    DOS.write((byte)(speedControl.getProgress()+3));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                speedControl.setProgress(84);
            }
        });
        steeringControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                try {
                    DOS.write(0x00);
                    DOS.write((byte)(steeringControl.getProgress()+3));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      //              e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                steeringControl.setProgress(35);
            }
        });

        MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask("192.168.12.101", 8899);
        myClientTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    View.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
            new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    try {
                        DOS.write(0x02);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          //              e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }};

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   //             e.printStackTrace();
    //            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     //           e.printStackTrace();
     //           response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     //       textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
}
```

App has two seekbars and 1 button. Seekbars controls steering and speed. The button controls break. When Every of these objects have their own listener. And when I touch any of these object the listener is called, which sends two bytes: first byte stands for nr of command, second is for value.
The problem is when I'm touching objects continiously, the recently called listener is interrupted by next called listener. So that arduino receive random bytes.
Anybody has an idea how to fix this?
How to make the listener be done completely?

Comment: Try wrapping DOS.write in synchronized method.

Comment: could you please point me where I have to paste "synchronized". I cannot get

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for asking you to take a step back. You could proceed in following way.

First make sure that the callback function are really interrupted. Verify this by capturing the data written to `DOS`. You can do this by constructing DOS with `FileOutputStream` instead of `socket.getOutputStream`. Now all your `DOS` write calls will write data to a file.

Run your app - do some fast UI activities - pull the file - verify that writes are really in random order. To simplify the verification problem, write only fixed known slider progress values instead of actual one. That will make your life easy identifying commands vs values.

Please, post the result. If problem still persists (*it shouldn't* :)), we will synchronize the DOS write calls.